# How to find the probability of the union and compliments of events?

Tags: probability

Given: p(A) = 0.6 and p(B) = 0.4 and p(AB) = 0.2

What does p(AB) mean, and how is it different from p(A U B)? How would I find p(A U B) with the given information?

How do I calculate p(A<sup>c</sup>B<sup>c</sup>)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(AB)$ generally means $P(A\cap B)$ and by inclusion-exclusion principle $$P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(AB)$$

$P(A^c)$ means the probability that $A$ doesnt happen.

Since we have $A\cup A^c = \Omega$ then $P(A\cap A^c) = 1$ and then, by the above law (noting $A\cap A^c =\emptyset$) we have

$$P(A^c) = 1 - P(A)$$

And similary $P(A^CB) = P(A^c \cap B)$ and since $B = (B\cap A)\cup (B\cap A^C)$ we have
$$P(B) = P(A^CB) + P(AB)$$

And then $P(A^CB) = P(B) - P(AB)$

Using the same idea, $P(A^CB^C) = P( (A\cup B)^C) = 1-P(A\cup B) =  1 + P(AB) - P(A) - P(B)$

Answer (score 1):

$P(AB)$ means the probability that events $A$ *and* $B$ occur. You could write it $P(A\cap B)$. The superscript $c$ means "complement" and $A^c$ means all outcomes not in $A$. So, $P(A^cB)$ means the probability that not-$A$ and $B$ both occur, etc.